# psycopg2 not connecting to Postgres on CentOS8

Tags: python, postgresql, centos, psycopg2, psql

I recently used the below code to connect to a Postgres database, query the database and run an insert statement. Please see the python file below.

db.py

```
import psycopg2 

#connect to the db
con = psycopg2.connect(

    host = "localhost",
    database = "mydb1",
    user = "postgres",
    password = "postgres",
    port=5432)


#cursor
cur = con.cursor()


#execute INSERT statment 
cur.execute("INSERT into persons (first_name, last_name, gender, email, date_of_birth, country_of_birth) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", ("Lloyd", "Thomas", "Male", "lloydthomas0702@email.com", "1987-02-07", "China"))

#execute SELECT query 
cur.execute("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM persons")

rows = cur.fetchall()

for r in rows:
    print (f"first_name {r[0]} last_name {r[1]}")

#commit the transaction - This must be included to update changes to the server
con.commit()


#close the cursor 
cur.close()


#close the connection
con.close()
```

I then compile the python script like so, here is the script working:

```
[lloyd@localhost postgresdemo]$ python3 db.py
first_name Audrie last_name Vasyukov
first_name Nefen last_name Philippard
first_name Leonore last_name Garthland
first_name Yank last_name Turfitt
first_name Benn last_name Pawley
first_name Tod last_name Easen
first_name Lloyd last_name Thomas
```

This is the output I expected. However, when I try this again on another CentOS 8 Linux machine, using the same code/process I receive the following error msg:

[image]

Any help or clue as to what is causing this error message would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Lloyd

Comment: Different settings in `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Is the postgres user set up to have access from this host?

Comment: Yes, I have used the same `pg_hba.conf` file, and the user is set up to have access. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.